# UV has more vertices than mesh?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I'm new to blender so I may be mis-explaining this my core problem is that when I add a texture to my mesh the render looks weird and triangulated. I have two meshes that have the same number of vertices,edges, etc (but some edges are different length/scaling). I transfer the UV map of one mesh to the other and then this is the problem that I encounter. In the UV Editing tab of the mesh the UV map looks good, but the texture looks weird (see screenshot) - I noticed that if I try to move a vertex in the UVmap it often won't move all the edges, but seems to be a duplicate vertex with only some edges connected. I have screenshots attached that hopefully explain it better than I am.

The red circle is around one single vertexc in the mesh, but is represented by 5 vertices in the UV map. I assume this is causing my trianglular artifacting I'm seeing.

[image]

Comment: The UV is split, each face can be seperated in the uv editor, despite being connected in the mesh editor. You can reconnect them by merging.

Comment: thank you for the comment! how do I merge them? I've tried Weld, merge by distance, etc. When I weld them they all line up on top of eachother but aren't a single vertex stil.

Comment: Press the space bar (or whatever shortcut you have set to bring up the search menu, and type in "Merge UVs by distance"  That should do the trick.

Comment: Hi I have tried that but that doesn't seem to work. Even when I am sure I have merged UV's by upping the threshold I still get those weird overlapping ones. I have noticed they are each their own UV island. Could that be the issue? I just want to merge it all into one big UV for the face.

Comment: You try unwrapping it again. Or welding the uverts together